# Slide right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm using this popular plugin for featured slider: http://slidesjs.com/

However for the arabic site, we need the sliders to go in the opposite (right to left) direction but there's no support for it.

```
function animate(direction, effect, clicked) { ... }
```

... although animate function has the direction argument but Its only for next/prev not all sliders.

Full script is here: http://pastebin.com/rRKR32nb

I'd appreciate any help. thanks!

Comment: So whats your question?

Comment: @Wezly how do I modify the script to get slides from right to left like it goes from left to right currently.

Comment: i dont think, thats that easy. there is no answer which will help you. you need to do it. i would just search for a plugin which has the option to define the direction...

Comment: turned out it was simple :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are http://pastebin.com/0Ta3Qh5R

I also highlighted the changes.

Good luck.